# Ubuntu touch: changing standard reminder time (possibly feature request)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

Is it possible to change the standard reminder time on Ubuntu touch calendar ?
In my Google calendar, the standard reminder time is 15 min, while Ubuntu touch has 0 min reminder time. When I enter a date in touch, I always forget to enter reminder time.

Answer (score 1):

I looked onto the sources of the current developer version. There it is 15 minutes by default. So, it'll be fixed.

Maybe someone can explain or link to guides about installing developer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if / how it's possible to change the **default** reminder time setting (i searched but couldn't find one), but since currently there is / was a bug related to reminder time settings **at all** probably this would have **no effect anyway**.

Currently the reminder **always** starts at the start time of the event, no matter what you choose (e.g. if you set it to "remind me 1 hour before the event starts", there just will be a reminding notification exactly at the start of the event, not one hour before).

A bug fix seems to be committed since 2015-05-22, so hopefully the problem will be gone with the next Ubuntu Touch or Calendar app update, which AFAIK is scheduled for around next week.

Please see

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+bug/1419001

for details... :)

regards

Comment: tried the today released patch with google calendar with no effect. also i have different reminder times for my dates. so this solution is not usable.